# MySQL pagination: Avoid newly added items in new pages

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I am making a web application using cakephp which makes use of comments. Users can create, read and delete their comments. It has a form where users can post new comments and immediately below that form, all relevant comments are shown using mysql pagination and ajax. First page: 1 comment, 2nd page: another 3 and then 5 more... 
Now when a user adds a new comment, that comment is prepended to the list of comments. Now if a user loads subsequent pages, the same comment appears in the end. How can we paginate it such that the newly added comment does not appear again?
The user can add as many comments at once as he wants and the first comment displayed could be a random one but subsequent pages have a well defined order. 
My current solution: I am maintaining an array 'exclusionList' which has all the preloaded comments in that ul picked up via jquery and sent to php using ajax. This solves the purpose but I think it's not a good way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: send the limit and offset data when requesting newer comments

Comment: hjpotter92: Think of it like the database has currently 10 comments. Now a user comes and adds 5 more. Now those 5 are prepended to that list and my back end has no idea if those new comments were recently added and are not supposed to be displayed. Using offset and limit, i can specify the page number and number of items in that page but how could I query to exclude those new items?

Comment: You could store the time when you come to the page with pagination and add condition that the rows must be older than the stored time. But it will be even more confusing for the user to not be able to find those 5 new comments. I would rather leave the pagination and store the `totalCount` and if you find out the totalCount is higher during browsing pages, just let the user know, there're 5 new comments... Hope it helps